# Heroku Error? Saying that my package.json is missing things

Tags: heroku

When using Heroku, I get this error message in Terminal:

```
(node:59291) Error Plugin: heroku: could not find package.json with {
  type: 'core',
  root: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/heroku',
  name: '@heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks'
}
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: loadPlugins
plugin: heroku
root: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/heroku
See more details with DEBUG=*
```

Not sure where to start to fix this.
I tried installing Heroku via NPM when I already had the CLI installed, not sure if that's the cause...

Answer (score 0):

I had Heroku installed both via brew and `npm i heroku -g` the -g made it global which was installed in the location mentioned in the error. I uninstalled the npm version and it's back to normal. `npm uninstall heroku -g`